# How do I fix Tkinter in Python-3.7?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7

I've tried to create a window with Tkinter but it does not work...

I am using MacOS with Python 3.7.3 in VSCode.

Maybe you can help me by this:

```
from tkinter import *
root = tk.Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

I tried many of these code versions but every time I run any of these programms he tells me:

```
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

I'd really like to use Tkinter but I don't now what to do...
I hope you can help me!

Thank's

Comment: Did you install tkinter with pip? If I'm correct, that might be a problem. Pip should not be able to install tkinter properly

Answer (score -1):

I recommend re installation of python from official site.

Comment: Although this is one of his error,but his code will raise `NameError: name 'tk' is not defined` not `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'`.So problem is not here.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer but I couldn't solve the problem because when I write "sudo apt-get install tk-dev", I get: "sudo: apt-get: command not found". Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You are on macos?? If yes then please tell how you dowloaded python package? by Homebrew  or  official macOS installer ?

Comment: And yes I use macOS :)

Comment: I recommend to re-install python from the official [site](https://www.python.org/downloads/)

Comment: Ok now I installed Python with the macOS installer. Is that correct or should I install it differently?

Comment: try import tkinter